# Cannot get URL response via Ruby

Tags: ruby, url, response

I have an error connecting in Ruby to the URL listed below, even though the URL exists. Why is that?

```
1.9.3p194 :003 > require 'uri'
 => true 
1.9.3p194 :004 > require 'net/http'
 => true 
1.9.3p194 :005 > url = "https://blogs.oracle.com/ksplice/entry/introducing_redpatch"
 => "https://blogs.oracle.com/ksplice/entry/introducing_redpatch" 
1.9.3p194 :006 > url_parsed = URI.parse(url)
 => #<URI::HTTPS:0x00000001939288 URL:https://blogs.oracle.com/ksplice/entry/introducing_redpatch> 
1.9.3p194 :007 > response = Net::HTTP.get_response(url_parsed)
Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than use Net::HTTP, simplify your life and use Ruby's [OpenURI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html). Unless you need low-level control or visibility of low-level values, you'll find OpenURI is good enough:

```
require 'open-uri'
url = "https://blogs.oracle.com/ksplice/entry/introducing_redpatch"
open(url).read.size
=> 35493
```

Comment: With OpenURI, is it possible to get the response code? (For the old approach I used `response.code`.)

Comment: Yes, it's in the documentation about using a block with `open`. Use the `status` method.

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
url = "https://blogs.oracle.com/ksplice/entry/introducing_redpatch"
uri = URI.parse(url)
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)

response = http.request(request)
response.body
```

It's taken from here: http://www.rubyinside.com/nethttp-cheat-sheet-2940.html

Comment: What does it mean `http.use_ssl = true`? Why must we use SSL?

Comment: @Mika https uses SSL, it is HTTP plus SSL